# Issues integrating the Scandit scanner component into AXamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to integrate the scandit barcode scanner comp. into my project. I was able to get the scanner to scan and return a barcode but none of the other functionality seems to work.

Such As:

```
Picker.OverlayView.SetTitleMessage("Hello Title") 
Picker.OverlayView.SetBeepEnabled(true); 
Picker.SwitchTorchOn(true);
```

These seem to have no effect. Unfortunately the demo code is skimpy and incorrect (its missing a brace and it uses the wrong namespace you need "using Scandit;" not "using ScanditSDK".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

"using ScanditSDK" is used for iOS version of the Xamarin component. It is not that clearly listed in the example in the Xamarin store but the sample projects that come with the component give a working example.

There is currently a problem with the resources of the component because of some changes on Xamarins side. We have a local version that loads them properly so this will be fixed with the next update to the component (likely still a few weeks away because the next Android update contains a lot of new things and will be preceeded by a short beta). This should fix the SetBeepEnabled and SwitchTorchOn functions. The SetTitleMessage function only does something when the legacy picker is shown (and that change with the next release as well), essentially you shouldn't need to use this function.

Comment: The problem is "using ScanditSDK" is defined in the Android Specific example not some generic documentation.